# Display an Image from PHP mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, image

I have a PHP script to echo the contents of a Mysql table.
I'm using it as a  small CMS for a static page.

What I want to know is how can I go about displaying an Image in my PHP script.
I have a form that submits the Date, Title, Message, and Image.

I'm using the Image field to insert the URL of an image.
Whats the correct way of displaying the image on a page.

Below is my code:

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","name","password");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("databaseName", $con);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Blog");


while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo $row['Date'];
  echo "<br />";
  echo $row['Title'];
  echo "<br />";
  echo $row['Message'];
  echo "<br />";
  echo $row['Image'];
  echo "<br />";
  echo "<br />";
  echo "<br />";
  }

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

This is the outcome:

> 17th Feb
>   Title
>   Here is my Message
>   http‍://vickybeeching.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2011/09/canthearyou.jpeg
>   
>   
>   18th Feb
>   Title
>   Here is my Message
>   http‍://vickybeeching.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2011/09/canthearyou.jpeg

but I want the page to display the image not the URL.
I'm guessing just using the `<img></img>` tags, but I'm not sure where in the PHP.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained and the [deprecation process](http://j.mp/Rj2iVR) has begun on it. See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write code in image tag instead of echo directly.

Try this code.

```
echo "<img src='".$row['Image']."'/>";
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this code, but give image folder path perfectly

```
<?php
  $imagepath = "../uploads/";
  echo "<img src='".$imagepath.$row['Image']. "' alt='' height='200' width='200' /> ";
?>
```

According to need , you can change height and width of the image. but clarity differs.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
 echo $row['Image'];
```

replace like this

```
 echo '<img src="'.$row['Image'].'" alt="" />';
```